# Does encrypting Time Machine backups require auth on restore?

Tags: backup, time-machine

If I have an encrypted Time Machine backup and I take it to a brand new machine, will it:

1. Be possible to restore without any authentication
2. Require a password or iCloud identity
3. Not be usable
4. Something else?

By not mentioning this, the official docs imply to me that #1 is correct.

Comment: Well, how would you decrypt an encrypted backup without any form of password? Also, which official documentation are you referring to?

Comment: It could be keyed on the iCloud account, or on some key on the host mac itself.
I was reading this help article: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203981

Comment: It's also worth noting that I have an encrypted TM backup, but don't recall being prompted to set a password. I created it just recently so I'm pretty sure there's no password, unless it is using my local user account password.

Comment: The password for the drive is stored in your keychain if you don’t have to enter it when you attach the drive after ejecting it @Synesso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Time Machine encrypts a drive, you will have to enter the passphrase to get macOS to decrypt the drive. The drive will mount and all contents are garbled until the key to unscramble the data is provided to the driver that attached the drive to the desktop.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/choose-a-backup-disk-set-encryption-options-mh11421/mac

iCloud entanglement is for rescuing a user account, not full drive encryption. Your account password can sometimes get a drive decrypted if your keychain contains the secret for a drive.